# How to Run a C# code every 5 minutes automatically when a windows app. is open?

Tags: c#, loops

I want a code that when a user opens my program, a code start to do an action every 5 minutes. for example every 5 minutes a message alert comes on the screen.
And I want a code to stop this. For example when the user clicks on a button, this loop do not execute more.
Regards.

Comment: is your program displaying the message or a different program?

Comment: It's Displaying an Alert message.

Comment: Would you mind posting your approach so far? This site is not meant to provide complete solutions but to help solving specific problems. Nevertheless, have a look at System.Windows.Forms.Timer in case you are developing a Windows Forms application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the others have mentioned, use a System.Windows.Forms.Timer if you are using WinForms.  You'll be able to drag a Timer from the toolbox to your form, then it appears below your form.  Set the `Interval = 300000` (5 * 60 * 1000 to covert to milliseconds), and `Enabled = true`

```
   public class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         timer1.Enabled = false;
      }

      private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         MessageBox.Show("Annoying message");
      }

         /// <summary>
      /// Required designer variable.
      /// </summary>
      private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

      /// <summary>
      /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
      /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
      /// </summary>
      private void InitializeComponent()
      {
         this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
         this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
         this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
         this.SuspendLayout();
         // 
         // timer1
         // 
         this.timer1.Enabled = true;
         this.timer1.Interval = 300000;
         this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
         // 
         // button1
         // 
         this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(89, 49);
         this.button1.Name = "button1";
         this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
         this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
         this.button1.Text = "stop timer";
         this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
         this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
         // 
         // Form1
         // 
         this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
         this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
         this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 266);
         this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
         this.Name = "Form1";
         this.Text = "Form1";
         this.ResumeLayout(false);

      }

      #endregion

      private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
      private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Timer class and bind the Elapsed event to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the action can be executed by the same program the user is running, check out the Timer control. (Exact name and approach may vary depending on your platform, which you've told us nothing about.)

Answer (score 0):

For a primitive solution, have a look at [Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) and [MessageBox.Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show.aspx).